# "authenticated as: anonymous Groups that you are in" error when checking kubectl version

Tags: kubectl

I am trying to setup the kubectl tool in my machine to remotely manage Kubernetes cluster and also to use Helm. I am trying in Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

I am following the official Kubernetes documentation from the following link,

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/

I ran the following commands,

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y kubectl
```

And after when I am running the '**kubectl version**' command to verify the installation , I am getting the following ,

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", 
GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", 
BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:11:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", 
Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Error from server (Forbidden): <html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' 
content='1;url=/login?from=%2Fversion%3Ftimeout%3D32s'/> 
<script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2Fversion%3Ftimeout%3D32s'); 
</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>
Authentication required
<!--
 You are authenticated as: anonymous
 Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->
```

And also not finding the '~/.kube/config' file in machine.

Why do I get this authentication error when checking the kubectl version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to manually copy **.kube/** directory from you cluster node into your local **~/.kube**

If you don't have **.kube/** on the master node, copy it from /etc/kubernetes/kube.conf

```
mkdir $HOME/.kube
scp root@<master-public-ip>:/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf $HOME/.kube/config
```

You can also define the filepath of kubeconfig by passing in --kubeconfig parameter, i.e.

```
kubectl version --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config
```

Comment: from cluster only finding the http-cache inside .kube folder. That I already have here. In helm installation documentation it says that need to have .kube/config , but after kubectl installation also I don't have that configuration file. Do I need to manually create that config file for installing helm client and to implement helm init? . Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Jacob Simply copy it from /etc/kubernetes/kube.conf on the master node

Comment: I don't have kube.conf in my /etc/kubernetes. I only have admin.conf , scheduler.conf , kubelet.conf and control-manager.conf .

Comment: @Jacob kubelet.conf  - the  one you need